# Can you play NBA2kXX without spending real money for Virtual currency?

Tags: nba2k17

I would like to play with NBA 2k17: I never played a similar title (I am relatively old :-) But I was there when Commodore 64 and Spectrum ZX were the leading game-machines, ok?)

I found out this concept of Virtual Currency and it seems similar to smartphone games like Clash of Clans where you pour real money in exchange for some in-game token. Now, call me old-school if you wish, but I would like to know if the game is playable and enjoyable even without spending more cash on it after buying it (and 2 controllers for connecting to a pc).

I have [read here](http://support.2k.com/hc/en-us/articles/210838517-What-is-VC-and-how-does-it-work-) a short description and it seems that nothing major should be compromised but I would like to be sure about what I will be missing.

Comment: It's rare to see a game where Micro-transactions are needed to play the full game.  Especially a rather large 2kXX title.  I can almost guarantee that your experience will be enjoyable.  Smartphone games rely more on micro-transactions because typically the game is free from the get go, and uses ads in most cases as well for revenue.

Comment: @TimmyJim I think you meant **not** enjoyable, right?

Comment: @Vemonus no - what makes you think that?

Comment: @TimmyJim who doesn't like micro-transactions?

Comment: @venomous I don't like them, for example :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are asking about the PC versions since you mentioned buying controllers for PCs.

Yes you can play NBA 2k without spending any more micro transactions.  I have NBA2k11 all the way through 17 and I have never spent a single extra $ beyond purchasing the game itself.

Comment: Correct, PC. Thanks for providing your experience!